# Why doesn't React automatically optimize shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As we konw, if a component's parent has change its state, its all children components will do render vitual dom operation.The use dom diff to render.

[image]
[image]
If you use shouldComponentUpdate function to judge is there any differents between nextProps nextState and props state.If you judge no differents between them, you can return false in this function, then react don't do render vitual dom operation.

So, I want to know, why react let us do this improve performance operation myself?I think if they can do this operation, it better for us to use react.

Comment: "this improve performance operation" --- it's not immediately obvious why it should be an improvement. There are no absolutes in software development, especially in the performance optimisations.

Comment: If you look at the characteristics of the good framework or library, Flexibility is the common thing. We never know what difficulty or scenario will arise or what we have to do. It gives us the opportunity to control the code base of the project.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they hint at why in the [advanced performance section](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html) of the documentation.

Essentially, equality can't be accurately determined when using mutable data structures.